# sh to py conversion

Tags: python, shell

I'm currently converting a shell script to python and I'm having a problem.  The current script uses the results of the last ran command like so.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    testPassed=$TRUE
else
    testPassed=$FALSE
fi
```

I have the if statement converted over just not sure about the $? part.  As I am new to python I'm wondering if there is a similar way to do this?

Comment: Are you using `subprocess` to run external commands? If not, what *are* you using? Please share that code.

Comment: Also, `if command` is better than `command; if [ $? -eq 0 ]`. Just for future reference.

Comment: Yes I will be using subprocess to call external commands.

Comment: @JasonTempleman Then take its status and make your decision on it. (If you show code, we can help better.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into the `subprocess` module for that. There is a [`check_call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) method for looking into exit codes (this is one method, there are others as well). As the manual mentions:

> Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete. If the
>   return code was zero then return, otherwise raise CalledProcessError.
>   The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the
>   returncode attribute

An example of this is:

```
import subprocess

command=["ls", "-l"]

try:
  exit_code=subprocess.check_call(command)
  # Do something for successful execution here
  print("Program run")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
  print "Program exited with exit code", e.returncode
  # Do something for error here
```

This will also include output, which you can either redirect to a file or suppress like so:

```
import subprocess
import os

command=["ls", "-l"]

try:
  exit_code=subprocess.check_call(command, stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"))
  # Do something for successful execution here
  print("Program run")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
  print "Program exited with exit code", e.returncode
  # Do something for error here
```

Here is an example of a call with a non-zero exit code:

```
import subprocess
import os

command=["grep", "mystring", "/home/cwgem/testdir/test.txt"]

try:
  exit_code=subprocess.check_call(command, stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"))
  # Do something for successful execution here
  print("Program run")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
  print "Program exited with exit code", e.returncode
  # Do something for error here
```

Output:

```
$ python process_exitcode_test.py
Program exited with exit code 1
```

Which is captured as an exception that you can handle as above. Note that this will not handle exceptions such as access denied or file not found. You will need to handle them on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You might want use the [sh module](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/#exit-codes). It makes shell scripting in Python much more pleasant:

```
import sh
try:
    output = sh.ls('/some/nen-existant/folder')
    testPassed = True
except ErrorReturnCode:
    testPassed = False
```